# VueJS: i18n not updating when used in computed prop and data prop

Tags: vue.js, localization, internationalization, vuejs2, vue-i18n

I installed the vue-i18n (http://kazupon.github.io/vue-i18n/en/) library for localization in VueJS project.

So I'm now trying to use it and when switching between languages, data to be updated. So here is how I tried to use it:

Example 1:

```
<template>
    <h1>{{ $t('message.hello') }}</h1>
</template>
```

Example 2:

```
<template>
    <h1>{{ msg }}</h1>
</template>
```

Where the code from the component looks like:

```
<script>
export default {      
  data() {
    return {
      msg: this.localeTest //which is showing undefined all the time
      //here I also tried the "msg: this.$t('message.hello')" and
      //in this case the value of the inital language is displayed
      //but then it's never updated while switching languages
    };
  },
  computed: {
    localeTest() {
      return this.$t('message.hello');
    }
  },
  methods: {
    changeLocale() {
      if (this.$i18n.locale === 'ja-JP') {
        this.$i18n.locale = 'en-US';
      } else {
        this.$i18n.locale = 'ja-JP';
      }
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

The Example 1 works as expected, but I'm interested in the Example 2. For this I tried two scenarios (which are described in the comments in the code) but none of them is working as expected. I'm more interested to make it work the "computed property" scenario.

Comment: In Example 2, did you try 
`<template>
    <h1>{{ localeTest }}</h1>
</template>` ?

Comment: that was the solution!

Comment: First we need to understand that computed is nothing but data which has some small function returning a value. That's why as @ittus said it worked. And never use computed properties inside data. Data gets created before computed does.